# Sound recorded by webcam microphone is distorted in 16.04

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone

Sound, as recorded by Audio Recorder or Skype, is distorted when played back with RythmBox or Skype (sounds like a cartoon character). Microphone is a webcam (video is fine), and works perfectly with Windows. In Settings, audio input is set to "Microphone, Webcam C200" unmuted, and that same input is selected with Audio Recorder. RythmBox plays externally recorded music perfectly, so the problem is limited to the webcam mic.

How to fix? (I have limited unix desktop experience)

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue, I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_distorted_due_to_automatic_adjustment) and it solved the issue for me.

> If your microphone volume creeps up automatically and causes the sound
>   to be distorted, you can fix it by disabling mic boost:
>
> In
>   `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-internal-mic.conf`
>   and `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-mic.conf`,
>
> - Under `[Element Internal Mic Boost]` set `volume` to `zero`.
> - Under `[Element Int Mic Boost]` set `volume` to `zero`.
> - Under `[Element Mic Boost]` set `volume` to `zero`.
>
> Then restart PulseAudio:
>
> ```
> pulseaudio -k
> ```

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the answer to your post, and provide the link for reference from the next time onwards. Link-only answers are not allowed here and usually get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I just decreased the input volume bar in here. And it worked!!!

[image]

System Settings→Sound→Input

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found  the article [Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), I followed the instructions, and the problem was fixed.