# Ubuntu 18: how can I select a fix volume for my Mic , the volume is rising each time i speak and it gets over saturated

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have a problem with my Microphone. The fisrt time, my mic made a sound like a hot whistle kettle when i used zoom. I used the threads of many guys like
[Too much noise while recording sound from mic on 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588823/too-much-noise-while-recording-sound-from-mic-on-14-04-lts)

after that, the noise  I noted my voice with distortion and the volume of my mic was rising even it was initiallty below 50%.
I tried to many solution like

https://markandruth.co.uk/2017/10/18/fixing-ubuntu-16-04-massive-internal-microphone-distortion

[Sound recorded by webcam microphone is distorted in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853491/sound-recorded-by-webcam-microphone-is-distorted-in-16-04)

https://slimbook.es/tutoriales/linux/379-como-forzar-el-volumen-del-sistema-cuando-se-oye-muy-bajo

but the volume is always rising to the top even i fix below to 50% using:

+default mixer
+pavucontrol
+alsamixer

in the end, my voice is over saturated and worst

I appriaciated  any helps

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  By Ubuntu 18 do you mean Ubuntu Core 18?  (though it has no desktop, desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

i try to modified the files
analog-input-internal-mic-always.conf
analog-input-internal-mic.conf
analog-input-mic.conf

using off and zero for Boost option instead merge, but they do not work